# Clock with loops in R to rename time-stamped files

Tags: r, loops, rscript

I have to rename several tens of thousands of audio files of 5 seconds each, each of them coming from a file of 5 minutes (5minutes/5secondes = 60 files). To do this I need to define the time (hour, minute and second) of the beginning of the 5 minutes recording and I tried to make a clock that advances from 5 seconds to 5 seconds and that keep the values of seconds, minutes and hours in vectors to rename the files using these vectors like this:

```
stwd("")

name = "Car041512-2021-Pass1-Z2_20210914_211000_" #file name prefix 

hours = 21
minutes = 19
seconde = 9


for (i in 0:59) {
  
    seconde[i+1] = secondes + i*5 
    
    
if(seconde[i+1] >= 60) 
    seconde[i+1] = seconde[i+1] - 60
    minute[i+1]= minutes+1  

  if (minute >= 60)
    minutes = 0
    hour[i+1] = hours + 1
}

time = as.character(paste0(hour,minute,seconde))


list =list.files(all.files=F)

rename = paste0(name,time,".wav")

file.rename(list, rename)
```

I have a problem at the beginning of the loop. The seconds vector does not exceed 60 seconds but only during 2 cycles and I do not see why. This is the first time I've done loops with R and I must have made a lot of mistakes.

```
seconde
 [1] 9  14  19  24  29  34  39  44  49  54  59   4   9  14  19  24  29  34  39  44  49  54  59 64  69  74  79  84  89  94 99 104 109 114 119 124 129 134 139 144 149 154 159 164 169 174 179 184 189 194 199 204 209 214 219 224 229 234 239 244
```

The renaming of the files works correctly, it's just the loop that doesn't work correctly. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output for `seconde` ?

Comment: @RonakShah in this case the expected output for the seconde vector is: 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59 4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59 4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59 4 9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49 54 59 4

but for an audio recording that began at 22:35 minutes and 15 seconds the expected output is: 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 0 ...... 

 That' s why I specify at the beginning of the script the time of the beginning of the recording of the audio file. 

thank you in advance.